# foreach php выполнение методов в массиве

Tags: php, foreach

Есть задача. 1.1, 1.2 - выполнены.
Проблема с 1.3

1.1. Абстрактный класс TriangleAbstract.php реализует конструктор в котором автоматически задаются стороны треугольника. У класса есть несколько абстрактных методов, которые должны быть реализованы в классе Triangle. Следоватьельно, необходимо создать класс Triangle, унаследоваться от класса TriangleAbstract. Для абстрактных методов создать реализацию необходимых функций описанных в комментариях к ним в родиельском методе.

1.2. Созданный класс Triangle необходимо подключить к файлу triangleTest. В массив triangleArray добавить 10 объектов типа Triangle (Условно, поместить в массив 10 треугольников).

1.3. Пройтись циклом фор-ич по triangleArray и выполнить реализованные методы. Вывести результат для каждого треугольника, каждый вывод подписывается с пояснением, что означает данный параметр (или к какому методу относится).

Не могу что то нормально всунуть код сюда
Вопрос каким образом можно через foreach выполнить все эти методы?

Comment: Чтобы "всунуть сюда код" нажмите на вопросик в верхнем правом углу поля редактирования вопроса и прочитайте справку.

Comment: в цикле их можно выполнить, в цикле

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Список методов можно получить функцией `get_class_methods`

```
class Triangle {
    public function method1() { echo 'Method 1 '; }

    public function method2() { echo 'Method 2 '; }

    public function method3() { echo 'Method 3 '; }
}

$triangle = new Triangle();
foreach (get_class_methods($triangle) as $methodName) {
    $triangle->$methodName();
}
```

Тоже самое можно сделать средствами библиотеки Reflection - у нее гораздо больше возможностей

Comment: Спасибо за наводку!